# Does flyway support Auth key based credentials for Snowflake

Tags: flyway, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Using flyway to manage our snowflake objects, but would like NOT to use user/password based authentication and instead use user+ Auth-key based authentication mechanism supported by Snowflake.

```
flyway.url=jdbc:snowflake://<myaccount>.snowflakecomputing.com/?private_key_file=<abs_path_to>/.ssh/rsa_key_fdb_user.pem&db=mydb&warehouse=etl_dev_wh&role=etl_dev_role&user=etl_dev_user
```

However, with the flyway.url set to above pointing to my location of private_key_file, it simply prompts me for a "Database password:" from the command line -

```
./flywaydb/flyway -configFiles=<absolute_basepath>/conf/flyway-dw.conf info
```

I was hoping that the user's Auth would get done based on the private key provided.

Comment: This reveals a limitation in Flyway's Snowflake support. Could you make an issue about it so we can improve the user experience? https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues. Thanks :)

Comment: sure, https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2677

Comment: Great, thanks. We have a fix that will be shipped in v6.2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please edit your config file and enter a *dummy* password as flyway.password:

```
flyway.password=wrongpassword
```

It should stop asking password and connect to Snowflake with the private key, in case you configured your user with rsa_public_key:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html#privatekey-property-in-connection-properties

Comment: Thanks. I ended up with multiple tweaks to get this working - a) upgrade to snowflake-jdbc-3.12 (from 3.10); b) additional param to jdbc string authenticator=snowflake_jwt and c) as indicated above explicitly set flyway.password=""